# Grails, controller is not called but the view updates

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, gsp

I have a very strange problem where a view is updated but the controller is never called. The controller is not scaffold and view/action name is "list".

The head of the controller looks like this:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER','ROLE_SALES', 'ROLE_SUPPLIER'])
class Orders_and_StoreController {
    def springSecurityService
    def list(Integer max) { 
        System.out.println("Controller List <<<<<<<<")
        def orders = Orders.list()
```

I've put a System.out.println to see if it's called but the printout never shows. 
I can click on links that routes me to another view where I can make an update and return to the original view. But the controller is not called.
If I make a change in the controller, could be just changing a comment, and then update the controller, the controller is called. And it continues to be called (as it should) until you restart the program.

I don't understand whats happening here, how could the page ever show up if not the controller is called first?

my url looks like this:
     http://localhost:8080/orders_and_Store/list
And if I click on link here at my computer the page displays but the controller is not called.
That's a big problem as the controller does a lot of filtering for the view.

Anyone that can have an idea or tips that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: I would start by renaming your controller and directory where gsps live, don't think Grails is going to like the naming, stick to camel case

Comment: That did it! Thank's! I still wonder what really happend, I thought tha if naming was wrong, you should get a page not found or similar. But here everything was fine except no filtering was done, and the how could it start to work after I updated the controller while the program was running?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your controller and gsp directory using camel case.

I don't know exactly why you've experienced this behavior but I'll hazard a guess that it's something to do with the underscore which has a special meaning for some Grails facets.

I've had issues before just combining multiple uppercase letters e.g. `myLEDController` and `myLED` gsp directory which was resolved by changing to `myLedController` and `myLed` respectively.